# Ruby gem gosu not installing, what's wrong

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am using a Raspberry Pi B 2 running Rasbian. It came with Ruby preinstalled on the card. I would like to install the ruby gem Gosu, but even with the internet working it still won't download and install the gem.

```
Fetching: gosu-0.13.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gosu:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
The Gosu gem requires some libraries to be installed system-wide.
See the following site for a list:
mkmf.rb can\'t find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/gosu-0.13.3 for  inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/arm-  
linux/2.1.0/gosu-0.13.3/gem_make.out
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Post the output in your question.

Comment: I have edited the question so it now contains the error message that I get.